# How an engine like Wolfram Alpha starts analysing a query?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence

I know this is fairly complex so I'll clarify my question a bit:

> "Wolfram Alpha"-like engines can receive a huge amount of different inputs in all possible combinations. 
>   How does one define the system's entry point of an inputted string?

I mean, suppose I type the following:
`integral of x^2 from 0 to infinity`
this is equal to
`x^2 integrate from 0 to infinity`
but they're not the same, of course, despite having some similarities.

I suppose it has something to do with language processing (just like compilers). I mean, does it break the words by some separator (like space) and then search for keywords like "integral", "integrate", and it goes from there?

Comment: Your question is much to deep and broad, however take a look at: [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Re9eB_j6m-0) and [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P7kX7BuHSFI) as a starting point.

Comment: I'm not sure about what to look on those videos. Is it cellular automata the basic principle underlying the wolfram alpha engine?

Comment: No, but if I remember correctly he does briefly talk about your question, basically it's a massive system that uses all sorts of techniques. There is no easy answer... some other suggestions, although I have no idea if these are the techniques are used, take a look at definite clause grammars (and other grammars), work on deep learning for NLP (word embeddings etc) and semantic networks. Probably one or more of these is used. Wolfram mentions in one of his talks that they are combining large knowledge bases together with a sophisticated look up/resolution scheme. Hope this helps!